# How to monitor over 500+ servers using Grafana from SQL server as data source

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

Currently we're monitoring our SQL servers running in Windows platform via MS SQL server reporting services using shared data sources. To confirm what I mean, we don't store data at centralized server to monitor over 500 target servers. We keep monitoring data on local SQL database servers and use shared data source in SSRS to create dashboards.

Now in our firm we're encouraged to use Grafana as dashboard since they have purchased or running some Grafana server licensing. What I know of Grafana instance is that it can be given to us to monitor SQL servers as described above.

My question is how would Grafana dynamically connect to those 500 plus servers? I see it creates data source once but how will I change or create multiple data sources when I have around 1000 servers to monitor?

Please suggest guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to code a bit and use [data source provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mssql/#configure-the-data-source-with-provisioning) and/or Grafana [datasource API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/data_source/#create-a-data-source) for it to pickup the new data source.

If you could set up a system (user-data/ init script/IaC) where this API is called everytime a new server comes up, then you will be able to maintain the data sources without maintainance.

Comment: @rohatgisanat- Thanks i am exploring the api way. Quick question, so in grafana if i monitor over 10K host, what you are saying , i will end up with 10K data sources. Is that viable in Grafana to have or is there a limit to number of data sources we can have in grafana

Comment: Ideally, there should be one datasource having multiple exporters pushing data into it. Each exporter itself may/may not handle multiple instances depending on how the exporter is designed.